# Setting a document's metadata fields

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I would like to set the `title` field of a `.docx` document. How can I achieve this in PowerShell?

Comment: what kind of document? docx, doc, pdf, jpeg.....?

Comment: [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/04/06/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-custom-properties-to-a-microsoft-word-document.aspx) looks like the way to go. Pretty ugly, though.